# Usage of the word fresh in a context

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, american-english, british-english

I have come across a sentence:

> weigh yourself first thing in the morning after getting fresh

among non-native English speakers. And seen some other sentences using the word "fresh" in a similar meaning. The highlighted sentence is supposed to be meant "weigh yourself after peeing n pooping".

I couldn't find a meaning of fresh in a dictionary that would mean this.

Is this usage of the word fresh correct?
If not, how else could one convey this in correct English.

Comment: It sounds very dodgy to me.

Comment: In American English we say "freshen up", not "get fresh".  To "get fresh" means for (traditionally)  a man to act crudely toward a woman.

Comment: Note, "First thing" contradicts "after getting fresh (freshening up)". Also, my father would say "morning ablutions", but that's probably a hang-over from his time in the British Army.

Comment: I would suggest 'after using the bathroom', which neatly covers both senses.

Comment: @ThePhoton your comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

"Get fresh (in the morning)" means showering and brushing your teeth, or doing your morning bathroom routine in general.

Since a morning bathroom routine often includes peeing and pooping, it could mean that, but it's not explicit or even implied.

So I'd call this a "loose" or maybe a *euphemistic* use of the phrase "get fresh".

Comment: What variety of English uses this expression? As an American, I've never heard it.

Comment: @ThePhoton By itself, the expression "get fresh" doesn't have that meaning for me either (Canadian), but how about "After you get fresh in the morning, ..."? In that context, do you understand "morning routine"? That's what I mean. For whatever it's worth, Urban Dictionary has an entry for it with that meaning, so it's not just me.

Comment: I would probably understand what was meant, but I would consider it "marked" usage (i.e. I would think the speaker is not fluent, or is speaking a different variety of English from what I'm used to).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know who your audience is, but in American English we say "freshen up", not "get fresh", when referring to activities done in the bathroom.

To "get fresh" is a somewhat old-fashioned expression that means to make a romantic or sexual proposal to someone, particularly when they do not want it. Historically it was almost always used to refer to a man approaching a woman, and was most commonly heard in the phrase, "don't get fresh with me."

Comment: We do say *freshen up* but I have never considered *freshen up* to include any type of biological purge.  I think of it meaning wash your face, comb your hair, brush your teeth, touch up your makeup, reapply deodorant, etc.  Have I been missing a clue all these years?

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther, I agree the primary meaning is about cleaning, but we often use euphemisms that allude only to cleaning when we really mean we are going to relieve ourselves. Even calling the place we do it a "bathroom" is a kind of euphemism that conceals the real function.

Comment: I agree. If I tell someone I'm going to freshen up I could mean any number of things.  But this is not me talking to my dinner guests.  This is advice on the process of weighing yourself.  One step being *purge before weighing yourself*.  My point being that telling someone to *freshen up* and then weigh themselves **does not** suggest that one should purge.  I would not make the connection.  I think many (most?) would not make the connection.  If you want someone to purge before weighing themselves, I think you will need to suggest that more explicitly.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther, I agree, it wouldn't be the clearest term to use in OP's example. The point of my answer is that we (Americans, anyway) don't use the term "get fresh" for any of the activities that happen in the bathroom, and the closest term we have for this is "freshen up". For what it's worth, if they used the word "purge" I would assume they meant vomiting and not pooping, so I don't think that's the ideal term to use either.

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to express that someone should weigh themselves after defecation and peeing and I wanted to say it in a polite and clearly understandable way, I would, as a speaker of AmE, be at a loss.  We don't have a generally agreed upon, polite way way to say this.

I would say

> Weigh yourself first thing in the morning after your morning purge.

and hope that no one found my statement to be crude language.

Kate makes a nice suggestion in the comments,

> Weigh yourself first thing in the morning after using the bathroom.

This is a very modest and understandable way to say it.